# Class 'ConsoleTVs\Charts\Charts' not found

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, charts

I tried to use Laravel charts - consoletvs/charts:6.*,

i using 
**serveice providers**

```
ConsoleTVs\Charts\ChartsServiceProvider::class,
```

**Alias is**

```
'Charts' => ConsoleTVs\Charts\Charts::class,
```

In my controller i using **use Charts**

```
$chart = Charts::new('line', 'highcharts')
            ->setTitle('My nice chart')
            ->setLabels(['First', 'Second', 'Third'])
            ->setValues([5,10,20])
            ->setDimensions(1000,500)
            ->setResponsive(false);
```

Here I facing issue is:

> Class 'ConsoleTVs\Charts\Charts' not found

I can't understand what's going on please help to find out this issues.

```
PHP version is 7.3.2
Laravel version is 5.5.45
Chart version is 6.3
```

Comment: check the class is included above or not in the controller

Comment: I might be missing something, but when I check their [Github-repo](https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts), I can't see any class called `ConsoleTVs\Charts\Charts`.

Comment: I don't know what i'm missing here

Comment: In my opinion, their documentation wasn't that good, but it looks like you need to create a chart class. [Read more in the manual.](https://charts.erik.cat/create_charts.html#create-a-chart-class) If that doesn't help you, I would recommend asking the developers for help. SO isn't really the correct place to ask for support on third party libraries.

Comment: then where can i get the support for this

Comment: two days i'm struck with this

Comment: If you can't get it working, you can always post an issue on their github?

Comment: I post there also still i didn't get any rly

Answer (score 0):

I Found the issue and i fixed this the version only working 
[this GitHub version is working](https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts/tree/5.4.0/docs/5#installation)

Answer (score 0):

When you use their generators (php artisan make:chart), it says the Library is optional. However, when I omit the library I ran into this error. I corrected it by removing the generated class, and regenerating it specifying the library I wanted (php artisan make:chart Fubar Echarts).

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the Following and see if it will work for your case:

```
$chart = Charts::create('line', 'highcharts')
            ->setTitle('My nice chart')
            ->setLabels(['First', 'Second', 'Third'])
            ->setValues([5,10,20])
            ->setDimensions(1000,500)
            ->setResponsive(false);
```

You also need to change the setTitle() attribute to title(),setLabels() to labels(),setValues() to values(),setdimensions() to dimensions() and setResponsive() to responsive().

Comment: You also need to change the setTitle() attribute to title(),setLabels() to labels(),setValues() to values(),setdimensions() to dimensions() and setResponsive() to responsive().